# What are best valid offpage SEO techniques? as per google's latest algorithm

Tags: seo, google-panda-algorithm, google-penguin-algorithm

I am trying to find and use offpage SEO techniques for my website but most of search telling me that google has updated SEO algorithm and some offpage techniques now google is considering as SPAM.

So anyone can list out valid offpage SEO techniques please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a lot of people get very fixated on SEO "techniques" and what the latest algo is. Basing your decisions on the very frequent changes that Google makes is not the best way to run a site or a business. Unless, you are using black hat techniques and are trying to stay ahead of Google catching you.

**Focus on things you can control**

You will never guess what the next algo update will bring or how it might or might not effect your site. Additional, those changes might become reversed or obsolete. So focus on things that you can fully control. Content Quality, Content Strategy/Inbound Marketing, User Experience, Site Performance and etc.

All of the aforementioned items will lead to quality backlinks, social sharing and return visits.

Ask yourself:

Why would someone visit my site?

Does it provide value?

Is it something that people are interested in reading about?

You can control every aspect of this and you will be rewarded if you pay close attention to what your target audience wants and not what the latest link bating fab everyone is trying this month.

Comment: Excellent! I would add the old advice of creating quality back links and encouraging organic back links. I would also add having patience too. This is a race that the tortoise always wins. I am absolutely frustrated with the SEO topic de' jure influence over the past decade. It confuses webmasters and can actually harm a sites SEO.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. I have been pretty fed up with it myself. There is so much of this nonsense out there. It gives SEO and people who practice it a bad rap. The amount of times I have heard people refer to SEO in meeting as pseudoscience is sickening. But they kind of do have a point when there is all this junk.

Comment: I have been at this stuff since writing protocol stacks and device drivers back in the ARPA-Net days which became the Internet. I was there for part of it. I worked with some niche search engines and got a nice peek into some Google internal documents. What I found is that this really is not rocket science. Most Google patents are rather simple and anything they do that is technically cool, exists in (non-SEO) research documents on the web. All these daily gyrations are just silliness in making a name for ones self- self aggrandizing. People by the bull and it frustrates me to no end.

Comment: @dasickle - thank you so much for your excellent answer.

Comment: @HelpingHands - you are very welcome and good luck. Remember, stick to the basics and thing about your audience.